# How to change the height of the contextual action mode on lollipop and above device?

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I have implemented the floatingsearchview from [here](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview). In my activity i am also having the action mode which is enable on long press on list item.On pre-lollipop the action mode overlays the whole searchview but on post lollipop devices it doesn't as seen in the pictures below

[image: lollipop and above without action mode]

[image: Pre-lollipop without action mode]

[image: Pre-lollipop with action mode which is correct behavior]

The problem is highlighted in below image.

[image: lollipop and above with action mode Problem]

So i want to increase the height of the action mode how can i do it.Well i already tried with styles attribute in style file.My activity current used style is shown below.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ContexualActionMode">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/actionModeBachgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

I also tried this but no solution.

```
<style name="Widget.ActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/action_mode_background</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="android:height">70dp</item><!--or something-->
</style>
```

with activity style

```
<style name="AppTheme.ContexualActionMode">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@Widget.ActionModeStyle</item>
</style>
```

can any one help me please.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you found your answer (hopefully) after this long but I was just struggeling with this issue and what worked for me is this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">

    <item name="background">@color/Blue</item>
    <item name="height">104dp</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/myTitleTextStyle</item>

</style>
```

and this in your appTheme style

```
<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionMode</item>
```

it finally worked for me when i removed the `android:` prefix from the items